# Get if checkboxes checked using names

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to create a true/false quiz form filled with questions from mysql database and save the user's answers depending if it's true or false(if he checks checkboxes or not) and insert them into the database but in the same column 
like this example: id_question: true; id_question:false; ....
so i decided when the user load the form, the name of the chackbox will be filled with the questions ids and combine each id with each user's answer but i didn't figure out how to do it.

This is my code:

```
<?php include('CodePHP/my_database.php');
     $questions = get_questions();



/*------------------------- add into database --------------------------------*/
    $ids_qst = $answers = [];
    if (isset($_POST['submit_answers'])){

    }
?>

<form action="" method="post" role="form" class="questionForm">

                <?php foreach($questions as $cle=>$question) {?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10"><p><?php echo $question['question'] ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <span class="outerDivFull" >
                            <span class="switchToggle">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $question['id_qst']?>" id="<?php echo $question['id_qst']?>">
                                <label for="<?php echo $question['id_qst']?>">Vrai/Faux</label>

                                <?php 
                                        /* Ajouter id question dans la liste des ids*/
                                    array_push($ids_qst, $question['id_qst']);?>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php }?>

        <div class="text-center">
            <button name="submit_answers" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Valider</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Annuler</button>
        </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours thinking and testing, i did found my answer alone 
Instead of using checkboxes, i had to use radio buttons because it's true/false quiz

This is my code for others that will need help:

```
<?php
    $user_answers = "";
        if (isset($_POST['submit_answers'])){
               foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
                   if($key!='submit_answers'){
                       $user_answers=$user_answers.$key.":".$value.";";
                   }
           }
        }
        echo $user_answers;
    ?>

   <span class="radio-group btn-group" >
       <input type="radio" class="checkmark" name="<?php echo $question['id_qst']?>" value="True">
       <label>True</label>
       <input type="radio" class="checkmark" name="<?php echo $question['id_qst']?>" value="False">
       <label>False</label>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as your input is named when you send the post request your $_POST variable should display checked inputs as 1. That works for checkboxes and radio button input types. In your backend php script you can run your logic based on that.

Comment: I know but it's named with questions ids , the checkboxes are filled from the database, I can't figure out how to get those names and check if each checkbox is checked or not.  And when I do  my checking i fill an array with each id and the user answer like this: $my_array=[id1: true, id2: true, id3: false ].